# Magic Mouse not scrolling!

Tags: imac, mouse

Just bought the magic mouse 2 it's working but not scrolling up and down.  When I go into system preferences and click on mouse, it shows there is no mouse found!  Help!

Comment: Try plugging it into your iMac via USB (and a lightning cable) and make sure it has charge!